# Connect to Postresql database from Google Colab

Tags: python, database, postgresql, database-connection, google-colaboratory

I am trying to connect my Google Colab to my Postgres DB. When I try to connect to from Jupyter Notebook it's working, so I'm guessing that my credentials are fine. This is the error that I got:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>
> Is the server running locally and accepting
> connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

How can I solve it? My Postgres running on my machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice to edit post title to say "Postgresql", as it is missing the "g". Might be useful for search ranking

Answer (score 7):

You can also install PostgreSQL in Colab.

```py
# install
!apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib &>log
!service postgresql start
!sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE USER root WITH SUPERUSER"
# set connection
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.feedback=False 
%config SqlMagic.autopandas=True
%sql postgresql+psycopg2://@/postgres
```

Then you can query using `%sql` or `%%sql` magic

```py
df = %sql SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
df
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you how can I get some documentation about it? I couldn't find anything. In addition, where does this database is located? I mean, if I close the notebook and start again, will I find the database again?

Comment: There's almost no doc on how to install PG on Colab. The database is in Colab machine, in Google Cloud. If you close it, the database disappear. You need to recreate it every time. Or you can dump it to store in Google Drive, then load it again next time.

Comment: how to change the data directory and enable saving / loading from google drive?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Jupyter` is working locally, that's why it sees `Postgres`. `Google Colab` is somewhere in the clouds, so it doesn't :)

You need to connect `Colab` to your local runtime:

> Connect to the local runtime: In Colaboratory, click the "Connect" button and select "Connect to local runtime...". Enter the URL from the previous step in the dialog that appears and click the "Connect" button. After this, you should now be connected to your local runtime.

(for details like *URL from previous step*, see source: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)

Then you can try something like:

```
%sql postgresql://username:@localhost:5432/username
```

but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But if I will do it, could I get to the files that are in my drive? I am using them in other cells in the code.

Comment: why don't you test it? :) i think yes, connecting to local runtime doesn't cancel your online drive connection