# Unable to connect to postgres sever from google colab using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, google-colaboratory, psycopg2

i keep getting errors attemping to connect to postgres from google colab,however on pycharm these same code connects to the server easily. Here is the code:

```
import psycopg2

params = {
    "host"      : "localhost",
    "database"  : "somedb",
    "user"      : "postgres",
    "password"  : "mypassword"
}
def connect(params):
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    conn = None
    try:
        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
         
    return conn

connect(params)
```

errors i am getting

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Should `**params_dic` be `**params`?

Comment: That was a **typo error** while i was typing the command to unpack the dictionary. The error  in the question still remains if **params**  is used. The question has been edited.

Comment: Any chance you have tried explicitly specifying `"127.0.0.1"` in place of `"localhost"`?

Comment: returned :Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Seems like you need to connect to your local runtime. The 2nd answer to this question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030755/connect-to-postresql-database-from-google-colab

Comment: Yea i am checking it out as the code runs perfectly on jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that on the list of allowed IP addresses in your PostgreSQL serever you've included:
34.0.0.0/8 and 35.0.0.0/8 which are the addresses for Google Colab.