# Making PostgreSQL Accept Python connection

Tags: python, postgresql, pipeline, psycopg2

I looked for the last two days on Stack Overflow and elsewhere about how to configure psycopg2. To be sure, I am trying to connect python to PostgreSQL, but I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have switched the listenting_address to equal "*", so it must be a problem with pg_hba.conf. I have the following connections set up. I was just wondering, what if anything is wrong with these connections? What should I change? I have looked in the documentation, at videos, at Stack Overflow for about 10 hours, but nothing solved this problem.

```
local    all             all                         md5
host     all             all      127.0.0.1/32       ident

host     all             all    my_ip/24      md5 #######
host     all             all    ::1/128             ident

local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Comment: Is the Python script being run on the same machine that Postgres is running on?

Comment: Yes, on google colaboratory

Comment: This is not an issue with `pg_hba.conf`, you are not getting that far. This is mostly likely due to some combination of:  1) The Postgres server is not running and/or 2) It is not using port `5432`.

Comment: Ok, the database is definitely using 5432. And the server is connected. Is there anything else I would have to do to run the server? Also, I found under properties a parameter called connections and it was set to -1. Could that make a difference?

Comment: You will need to explain 'server is connected'? Where is the server located and how was it installed? Also explain 'under properties a parameter ...'? Add answers to this as update to your question. Remember we are not looking over your shoulder, you need to provide detailed information to move this along.

Comment: Seems like you are to connect to your local runtime. The second answer in this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030755/connect-to-postresql-database-from-google-colab