# How do I resolve the following error: '(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused'?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection, psycopg2, psql

I'm using google colab and I'm trying to use psql to execute sql commands from my colab notebook.

I installed postgresql using the postgres.app for Mac (10.14.6), python version 2.7.16. I am using the postgres app and pgadmin 4 to execute my work.

My code is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://myusrname:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb')
```

I then run:

```
%sql $engine.url
```

And I keep getting the following error:
"(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

I have triple checked and my username, password, hostname, port, and database name are all correct, so that is not the issue. The server is running on the specified port.

I have tried several previously given answers to similar questions.
I modified both my 'pg_hba.conf' and 'postgresql.conf' files as suggested:

pg_hba.conf:

```
 # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

  # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

postgresql.conf:

```
#listen_addresses = '*'
```

I have tried using my wifi IP address instead of 'localhost'. This didn't work either. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: I don't think Google Colab can connect to a postgres server running in your localhost, the only way I can think of is exposing your 5432 port to the Internet, which is most probably not what you want

Comment: OHH right, ok. Thanks. The problem is I have a large data file in my google drive and I'm trying to process it using SQL and I'm stuck on how exactly to do that. I can't download the file to my personal computer because it's too big. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030755/connect-to-postresql-database-from-google-colab can be of use, try both of those, the one with no upvotes seems to do exactly what you asked here

Comment: Thank you!! That worked. Now unfortunately I am having a new issue that I cannot 'COPY' information from my csv file in google drive into my psql table due to restricted permissions...